# Show content on click

Tags: jquery, wordpress, onclick, show

I am trying to use Jquery in a Wordpress page, exactly how it is done in this static HTML page: 
http://www.zestcatering.co.za/associates.html ( click on Wedding Concepts )

Any plugins out there to get this working?

Many thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Add a click handler to the weddingConcepts element when the document is loaded.

```
$(".weddingConcepts").click(function(){
    $(".weddingConceptsContainer").show();
});
```

This is assuming that the weddingConceptsContainer element initially has `display:none;`

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code.

> javascript:
>   $('#content').load('associate1.html');

It's basically saying to load the contents of `associate1.html` in the `#content` div. You don't need any plugins for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

That page is not static.

It is using jQuery and ajax.

One example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: $('#content').load('associate1.html');">Wedding Concepts</a>
```